# how to use the newAPIHadoopRDD in java?

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark

I'm trying to read from cassandra to JavaRDD following is my code

```
public class SparkWCassandra {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("local","spark Cassandra");
    String KeySpace = "retail";
    String InputColumnFamily = "ordercf";

    try {
        Job job  = new Job();
        job.setInputFormatClass(CqlPagingInputFormat.class);
        ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "localhost");
        ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
        ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KeySpace, InputColumnFamily);
        ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "Murmur3Partitioner");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SparkWCassandra.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
}
```

the next step should be using `jsc.newAPIHadoopRDD()` but I don't quiet understand what does the parameters mean and what should i pass to it.
the keyspace and table created in cassandra are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE salecount (product_id text,sale_count int, PRIMARY KEY (product_id));
  CREATE TABLE ordercf (user_id text,
  time timestamp,
    product_id text,
    quantity int,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, time));
  INSERT INTO ordercf (user_id, time, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('bob', 1385983646000,'iphone', 1);
  INSERT INTO ordercf (user_id, time, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('tom', 1385983647000,'samsung', 4);
  INSERT INTO ordercf (user_id, time, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('dora', 1385983648000,'nokia', 2);
  INSERT INTO ordercf (user_id, time, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('charlie', 1385983649000,'iphone', 2);
```

can anyone give an example on using newAPIHadoopFile? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really should try official DataStax Cassandra driver for Spark, which is available [here](https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-driver-spark/). It allows you to access Cassandra directly without Hadoop API. It is much easier to use and probably much faster.

Comment: thanks. but this is the driver for scala, can it be used with java?